# search on a xdocument using linq

Tags: linq, lambda, linq-to-xml

I have the following xml from a string:

```
<XMLClient>
  <ClientData>
   <Control type=1>BtnSave</control>
   <Control type=2>Suppliers.aspx</control>
   ...
   ...
   ...
  </clientData>
</XMLClient>
```

what I want to do is to return true or false using weather the record/node exists where the control's type attribute is 2 and the text equals Suppliers.aspx.

I want to use linq for this, and I don't know I guess I'm gonna need some linq expression, not quite sure...

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Comment: Pardon, but.. why are you still edited your question and ruined your xml code formatting?

Comment: Sorry this is my first question and I don't know what I did... I guess I removed the tag signs, but the answer made my brokenglass was great, thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("test.xml");

bool nodeExists = doc.Descendants("Control")
                     .Where(x => x.Attribute("type") != null && 
                                 x.Attribute("type").Value == "2" && 
                                 x.Value == "Suppliers.aspx")
                     .Any();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("xmlFile");
var result = doc.Root.Descendants("Control")
                     .Any(c => c.Attribute("type") != null && 
                               c.Attribute("type").Value == "2" && 
                               c.Value == "Suppliers.aspx");
```

Comment: Yes it works,  I used the XDocument.Parse(XMLString), but everything else basically the same thing, thanks !!